# How can I simplify this small code with a loop in AS2

Tags: actionscript-2

the following code I want to simplify:

```
    _root.botao1.onRelease = function(){
        follow=1;
    }
    _root.botao2.onRelease = function(){
        follow=2;
    }
    _root.botao3.onRelease = function(){
        follow=3;
    }
```

I have tried to implement it by the following code:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    _root['botao'+i].onRelease = function(){
        follow=i;
        trace(follow);
    }
}
```

Although it should work, when I trace back the current follow value it always return in '3', no meter if I actually click on the 1 or 2.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Just noticing that in your original code, you refer to botao1, botao2, and botao3; while in your loop, you'd be assigning botao0, botao1, and botao2.  Not certain why you are getting 3.  Just my opinion, I like to simplify code, too, but that particular simplification does not seem worth it in terms of your time lost to debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The reason all buttons print the same value is because all onRelease functions reference the same variable i, which contains the value 3 when the loop has finished executing.

An easy solution is to simply store the value of i each iteration of the loop to a variable on the clickable object:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   var mc : MovieClip = _root['botao' + i];
   mc.follow = i + 1;
   mc.onRelease = function(){
      trace(this.follow);
   }
}
```

Another solution that might be a bit harder to grasp is to define an anonymous function and call it immediately (notice the () at the end). This anonymous function stores the current value of i inside its own scope in a variable called follow, then returns another anonymous function (contaning the logic you want to run when onRelease is triggered). The function returned has access to the follow variable:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    _root['botao' + i].onRelease = (function() {
        var follow = i + 1;
        return function(){
            trace(follow);
        }
    })();
}
```